# A tabbed Android UX element similar to iOS App card?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, android, tabs, contextual-menu

Is there a standard Android layout that allows for tabs within a context menu? Something similar to the iOS app card would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Android Design Guide at the [Multi-pane Layouts](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html) section.  I think this covers what you are looking for.

[image]